# raise NeedDownloadError('Need ffmpeg exe. ' NeedDownloadError: Need ffmpeg exe)

Tags: python, python-2.7, ffmpeg, instagram-api, moviepy

I'm trying to execute a call to an unofficial Instagram API python library, after several errors for dependencies needed I fixed, I'm stuck at this one.

```
 File "C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\txts_pys_phps_programacion\Instagram-API-python-master\InstagramAPI.py", line 15, in <module>
    from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\moviepy\editor.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\VideoFileClip.py", line 3, in <module>
    from moviepy.video.VideoClip import VideoClip
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .io.ffmpeg_writer import ffmpeg_write_image, ffmpeg_write_video
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_writer.py", line 15, in <module>
    from moviepy.config import get_setting
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\moviepy\config.py", line 38, in <module>
    FFMPEG_BINARY = get_exe()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\imageio\plugins\ffmpeg.py", line 86, in get_exe
    raise NeedDownloadError('Need ffmpeg exe. '
NeedDownloadError: Need ffmpeg exe. You can download it by calling:
  imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This package relies on the `ffmpeg` executable to be in the PATH.

So just download it, install it somewhere, and add installation directory to PATH. make sure it can be accessed by typing:

```
ffmpeg
```

from the command line.

Comment: @BillBell thanks. Though, to be devil's advocate, in some cases it is required, when the answer is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 24):

Those final two lines in the error messages provide a valuable clue, and I installed moviepy only today so I remember a remedy.

```
NeedDownloadError: Need ffmpeg exe. You can download it by calling:
  imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()
```

- First `(sudo) pip install imageio`, if necessary.
- Now: `import imageio` and then `imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()`.

Comment: so this method doesn't need to put `ffmpeg` in the path I guess? I suppose that the executable is put in some python directory where it can be called from.

Comment: No, I didn't have to do anything else. Pure magic. I always end my efforts when the error messages go away. ;)

Comment: I use `ffmpeg` directly so it is in my path. I guess that made me ignore the error message (that clearly appears in the OP traceback). I think OP should accept _your_answer.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: We'll see what happens. No worries AFAIAC.

Comment: magic indeed! I'm on a cluster and don't have root right, but this solution still works.

Comment: @xslittlegrass: I definitely can't take credit for that!

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Ubuntu just try:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Else if you are using Windows just try to change ffmpeg.py 82th line from auto=False to auto=True

It will automatically download ffmpeg to the correct path once. Then `import imageio` and write down `imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()`

Will work.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using a mac do this.

pip install imageio (if not already installed).

Then create a .py file (python script).

In this file write this:

```
import imageio

imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()
```

Run this script in the terminal (i.e "python (insert .py filename here)" )

It installs FFmpeg in a directory that should be automatically added to your path. If not, add it to your path.

Then type

```
   ffmpeg
```

to make sure it's installed in your path.

Answer (score 1):

on mac,
this is the best way to install ffmpeg.
Open terminal and type.

```
$ brew install ffmpeg
```

you will be seeing it get installed.

```
==> Installing dependencies for ffmpeg: lame, x264, xvid
```

Answer (score 0):

At Windows, I'd fix this that way:

1. Manual download ffmpg from [github](https://github.com/imageio/imageio-binaries/tree/master/ffmpeg)
2. In the *Lib\site-packages\imageio\plugins\ffmpeg.py* file, change

   ```
   exe = get_remote_file('ffmpeg/' + FNAME_PER_PLATFORM[plat], auto=False)
   ```

   to

   ```
   exe = "PATH_WITH_FFMPG\\ffmpeg.win32.exe"
   ```